# Hausdorff measure and uniform subdivisions

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Sorry I never got to learn about Hausdorff measures so this may come as simple. Suppose
$$ A = \{x\in [0,1)^d: f(x)=0\} $$
where $f$ is analytic and nontrivial. Then $A$ is an analytic variety of dimension $d-1$. My intuition is that

(1) If we make a uniform subdivision of $[0,1)^d$ using $N^d$ points, then $A$ will contain $\sim N^{d-1}$ points of the subdivision.

(2) I also think we have more precisely
$$ \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{ \# \{n\in \{0,\dots,N-1\}^d: f(\frac{n}{N})=0\}}{N^{d-1}} = \mathcal{H}^{d-1}(A) .$$

Are these facts true? Thanks very much.

**Edit:** That's not true as stated, as commented by GEdgar. I am interested more specifically in $f(x) = \cos(2\pi x_1) + \cos(2\pi x_2) + \dots+ \cos(2\pi x_d)$.

Comment: (2) Is there some reason that any of the zeros of $f$ should be at rational points?  Say $f(x) = x_1+\dots+x_n-\sqrt{2}$. (1) is probably correct if $f$ is bounded on $[0,1)^d$.

Comment: Thank you GEdgar, I've edited the question.